# Show Others Images if Available Places

Tags: php, mysql

I want to show others image based on limit.

Table group images

```
| id | Name | Max places |
   1  Static      3
   2  Rotate      2
```

Table images

```
| id | group_id | url |
   1       1     https://ima.ges.png
   2       2     https://ima.ges.png
   3       2     https://ima.ges.png
```

I want to show images in my template based on Max available places on the groups. Let say I have 1 images to show in group static, then the groups will still have 2 more slot then show others images.

In conclusion, it still show 3 images in template.

```
1. images from https://ima.ges.png

2. images from default value

3. images from default value
```

The question is, how to do this based on mysql data? 
thanks for helping

Comment: sorry, alredy edit first post. thanks

Comment: Nope, I'm still not getting it. Perhaps see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Right now the images is only show 1 images. That is https://ima.ges.png and the rest is empty. I want to fill the empty places by 2 others images. Because the groups have 3 max places

Comment: Can you show us what you tried so far?

Comment: Others images is my images that I set it default from my template

Comment: I can only refer you again to my previous comment.

Comment: Can you please see this https://hyipweb.com. There they have only 1 images from server which is green banner. And the rest they show default value for available places banner. Can you get it?

Comment: So, this is just a simple loop in PHP.

Comment: Can you show me how?

Comment: Um, PHP isn't really my strong suit. I'd have one query on each table. I'd build a simple array out of the groups table, and a multidimensional array out of the images table, then I'd loop through the groups table, and echo images from the images table/default file according to how many images were allowed by 'max_places'; I can try to construct something later, if I have time, but it won't be very good.

Comment: Sounds good, waiting for it. I just can't figure out how the logical works

Comment: anyone can help me with this?